# perl - Split string by methods within the strings

Tags: regex, perl

I have two questions:

First, how can I split the following string into individual strings split by the methods within the string? I tried using regex, but was unsuccessful.

```
$objc = "- (void)method {
    NSLog(@"method");

    if (1 == 1) {
        //blah blah blah
    }
}

- (id)otherMethodWithProperty:(NSString *)property {        
    NSLog(@"otherMethodWithProperty:");

    return property;
}

-(id) methodWithMoreProperties: (id)property Property2:(UIView *)property2  Property3:(NSString *)property3 {
    id view = property;

    if (view) {
         NSLog(@"%@", view);
    }

    return view;
}"
```

Second question is after splitting into individual strings, is it possible to grab each property and add it within the respective string?  For example:

I take the string:

```
"-(id) methodWithMoreProperties: (id)property Property2:(UIView *)property2  Property3:(NSString *)property3 {
    id view = property;

    if (view) {
         NSLog(@"%@", view);
    }

    return view;
}"
```

grab the properties "property, property2, property3" and add them within the string after the first "{" and before the last "}":

```
"-(id) methodWithMoreProperties: (id)property Property2:(UIView *)property2  Property3:(NSString *)property3 {
    NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n%@", property, property2, property3);
    id view = property;

    if (view) {
         NSLog(@"%@", view);
    }

    return view;
    NSLog(@"FINISH: %@\n%@\n%@", property, property2, property3);
}"
```

I've been googling and testing code for hours and I've only managed, using regex, to get the method name

> -(id) methodWithMoreProperties:

and add it within the string, but haven't been able to grab the properties themselves and add them after the first { and before the last }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not all was done by regex, but I think it's more readable

```perl
# split string into methods
my @methods = split /^-/m, $objc;

foreach my $method_content (@methods) {
    my $method_declaration = (split /{/, $method_content, 2)[0];

    my ($method_name, @properties) = $method_declaration =~ /\)\s*(\w+)/g;

    if (@properties) {
        my $sprintf_format = join '\n', ('%@') x @properties;
        my $sprintf_values = join ', ', @properties;
        my $begin_message = sprintf 'NSLog(@"%s", %s);',         $sprintf_format, $sprintf_values;
        my $end_message   = sprintf 'NSLog(@"FINISH: %s", %s);', $sprintf_format, $sprintf_values;

        $method_content =~ s/{/{\n    $begin_message/;
        $method_content =~ s/}\s*$/    $end_message\n}\n\n/;
    }

    print "-$method_content";
}
```

but the `$end_message` should be better put before the methods's `return` or it'll never be triggered.

Comment: thanks so much, this is exactly what I needed. & yes, I know about the expressions going before the return :) I just wanted it for methods without returns as well, but I'll be able to figure the rest from here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
my @matches = $objc =~ /(-\s*+\([^)]++\)(?>\s*+\w++(?>:\s*+\([^)]++\)\s*+\w++)?+)*+\s*+({(?>[^{}]++|(?-1))*+}))/g;
```

(you only have to costumize the capturing groups as you want)